# Style the div inside hyperlink; on hover

Tags: html, css

Actually I want to give hover to div which is inside hyperlink but I don't know how to in css.
These divs actually have background images attached to them in css.

```
<div class="header_menu">
   <div class="foa_logo"><img src="images/FOA-Logo.jpg"/></div>
   <div class="address"></div>
   <a href="#"><div class="home"></div></a>
   <a href="#"><div class="about"> </div></a>
   <a href="#"><div class="services"></div></a>
   <a href="#"><div class="contact"></div></a>        
</div>
```

Comment: What do you have for your CSS file so far? Also, there's no reason to use `divs` at all inside your links. You can simply set styles for the `a` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
element:hover {
  property: value;
}
```

By this, you can change the CSS properties of the elements when they are hovered over!

So for you, you will try it as:

```
.home:hover { // on the home div..
  // all the changes here
}
```

Comment: i want to make whole div hyper link.so when i move cursor over that div it changes it colour on mouse over :(

Answer (score 0):

```
div { 
  width:100px; 
  transition: width 2s; 
}
div:hover {
  width:200px;
}
```

replace div with `.foa_logo` if you want to select just that class.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a jsfiddle for you showing how to do the `hover` you want. I removed the `divs` in the hyperlinks, because they are not useful. You can simply set the styles for the `a` tags and then you get your `hovers`

http://jsfiddle.net/FHWb6/

```
.header_menu a {
    display:block;
    height:40px;
    width:100px;
    line-height:3;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background:url(); /*put your image here*/
    background-color:#CC0;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.header_menu a:hover {
    background:url(); /* put your hover image or position here */
    background-color:#ececec;
    color:#000;
}
```

I added some extra code in there just to do some base level styling - `color`, `height` and `width` will most likely change for you.